# If $\lfloor a-b\rfloor =2$, $\lfloor b-c\rfloor =3$, $\lfloor c-d\rfloor =4$, what is the sum of all possible values of $\lfloor a - d\rfloor?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers with $\lfloor a - b\rfloor = 2 , \lfloor b - c\rfloor  = 3 , \lfloor c - d\rfloor = 4$. What is the sum of all possible values of $\lfloor a - d\rfloor ?$ ($\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denote the greatest integer function)

**What I Tried**:

I got that:-
$$\rightarrow 3 > a - b \geq 2$$
$$\rightarrow 4 > b - c \geq 3$$
$$\rightarrow 5 > c - d \geq 4$$
But I seem to find no way to use these. One think I thought is to first find the maximum $(a - d)$ , then find the minimum $(a - d)$, and then consider all the integer values between the maximum and the minimum. The question is, how do you find that?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How about adding them?

Comment: $$(a-d)=\underbrace{(a-b)}_{\pm 2}+\underbrace{(b-c)}_{\pm 3}+\underbrace{(c-d)}_{\pm 4}$$

Comment: And $$ (x^{-2}+x^2)(x^{-3}+x^3)(x^{-4}+x^4) = \sum_{k\in\{\color{red}{1,3,5,9}\}}(x^k+x^{-k})$$

Comment: What is $d$ for? ANd whay do you need $[]$?

Comment: Basically $$|a-d|=|\pm 2\pm 3\pm 4|$$

Comment: Oh nvm , I thought that $[]$ meant the greatest integer function. From @JackD'Aurizio's comment I think it should mean the absolute value, I think I have figured it out as well.

Comment: If $|\cdot|$ actually stands for $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ then $(a-d)=(a-b)+(b-c)+(c-d)$ still holds and $(a-d)$ can be any number in the interval $[9,12)$.

Comment: In addition to the note by other users about the absolute value vs. the floor (integer value), there seems to be another problem in the text: there is no mention of $d$ in the expressions that you wrote. Did you mean to write  $|c-d|=4$ ?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a-d = (a-b) + (b-c) + (c-d)$

Now $[a-b]\le (a-b) < [a-b]+1$ etc.  so

$[a-b] +[b-c]+[c-d] \le (a-b) +(b-c)+(c-d) = (a-d) < [a-b] + [b-c]+[c-d] + 3$ so

$2 + 3 + 4 \le (a-d) < 2+3+4 + 3$

$9 \le a-d < 12$ so $a-d$ may be $9,10$ or $11$.

So the sum of all possible values (why do they *ask* these questions???) is $9+10+11 = 30$.